# Latex op Mac M1 chip?

Tags: mac, mactex

Hoe kan ik latex op mijn nieuwe macbook air M1 chip zetten? Ik heb van alles geprobeerd maar het lukt niet

[from Google Translate: How can I install latex on my new macbook air w/ M1 chip? I have tried everything but it doesn't work.]

Comment: Stel uw vraag in het Engels. Please pose your question in English.

Comment: Claims such as "I have tried everything" and "it doesn't work" aren't exactly descriptive. Please state what exactly you have tried. In particular, do state whether you've tried installing [MacTeX2020](https://tug.org/mactex/).